# How to change Track Color in ng2-nouislider

Tags: sass, angular5, nouislider

I am using NG2-Nouislider in an Angular 5 project. I have a slider that has two handles and I am trying to change the color of the shaded part that joins the handles. I have tried overriding the css classes in the .scss file for the component but it has no effect. This was the css used in the scss file:

```
.noUi-connect {
     background: purple;
 }
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle, .noUi-vertical .noUi-handle {
     background: purple;
 }
 .noUi-target.noUi-horizontal .noUi-tooltip {
 background-color: purple;
 }
```

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to override `CSS` in `.scss` file adding `!important`

```
.noUi-connect {
     background: purple !important;
 }
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle, .noUi-vertical .noUi-handle {
     background: purple !important;
 }
 .noUi-target.noUi-horizontal .noUi-tooltip {
 background-color: purple !important;
 }
```

and `encapsulation` to your `Component`

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-x",
  templateUrl: "./x.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./x.component.scss"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: This works but not how I wanted. By adding encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None it introduces the potential for style bleed. I want to just affect the styles of this component only.

Answer (score 1):

```
:host ::ng-deep .noUi-connect {
  background-color: blue;
}
```